# Triggers in Google Apps Script not firing correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a number of scripts that I oversee set up numerous users in Google Apps Script. Each of these is set up with an installable edit and installable open trigger.

For most users, these triggers fire just fine. However, for a couple of users, the edit trigger is not firing. Script authorisation scopes have not changed since the trigger was added, and removing and re-adding the triggers has been attempted to remedy the issue.

The same triggers fire correctly when set up from other people's accounts, but just not from the affected users. The affected users also do not have any other triggers set up.

Can anyone please provide any pointers as to what may be going on here?

Comment: Maybe those specific users are opening the spreadsheet in read-only mode. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) on Installable Triggers:
Triggers do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment) mode. Also, How do you know when your script is triggered?

Comment: I can confirm this is not the case as I have physically been with a number of them when it happened.
The script it triggers has a `Logger.log` statement on the first row collecting the event object which doesn't get done. Also there is no execution transcript.

Comment: Are the problem-accounts always the same? Could be something with email domain. Are the problems always at the same time of day? Could be quotas. Are the problems always with the same users? Could be permissions.

Comment: I think I'll pursue the email domain route as the accounts always are the same. Happens at all times of days so suspect not quotas, but yes, always same users but permissions have been checked. Many thanks